# Xcopy to multiple external drives using drive label

Tags: batch-file, command-line, disk, xcopy

I need to copy a number of files to multiple USB drives.
The USB drive letters are not static, so I need to create a script that will run the xcopy command on all USB drives with a label of "USB DISK".
I've found command lines that will do this for a single drive, but not multiple drives.

The command `"for /f %%D in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, Label ^| find "My Label"') do set myDrive=%%D"` works, but only on the last drive.

Is it possible to copy the files to all the drives at the same time, rather than one after another?

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f %%D in (
 'wmic volume get DriveLetter^, Label ^| find "My Label"'
) do start "Copying to %%D" xcopy "sourcespec" %%D:
```

should parallel xcopy your source files to each selected drive. `xcopy` options and specifications are in your court

Comment: Magoo, that is absolutely fantastic.  Thank you very much.